# How to combine rows into one, MS SQL Server management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, rows

I think this is a tricky one, How do you combine all of these rows into one? Is it possible? Maybe using temp tables, the values on the left from combo onwards are null but could contain a value. Any ideas?  Let me know if you've got any questions.

I would like to show just one line for this unit, i.e/ RecordNumber Reg_string Parts Materials Labour Combo Smart Total Estimate. Record number does not need to be selected in the query but might help when building the script. This is my script so far.

```
    RecordNumber   Reg_string   Parts   Materials   Labour  Combo    Smart    Total Estimate
1              AB12ABC      NULL    NULL        NULL    222.27   0        222.27
2              AB12ABC      NULL    NULL        NULL    76.7     0        76.7
3              AB12ABC      NULL    NULL        NULL    48.1     0        48.1
4              AB12ABC      NULL    NULL        NULL    49.4     0        49.4
5              AB12ABC      NULL    NULL        12      NULL     1        13
6              AB12ABC      NULL    NULL        NULL    255      NULL     255
7              AB12ABC      NULL    NULL        NULL    255      NULL     255
```

I would like the output to be like this please:

```
RecordNumber   Reg_string   Parts   Materials   Labour  Combo    Smart    Total Estimate

 1              AB12ABC      NULL    NULL        12    906.47   1        919.47
```

My script is this if it helps:

```
     SELECT     UnitData_Vehicle.Reg_String AS Registration, UnitData_Vehicle.VehID_String AS [Vendor Code], UnitData_Vehicle.Manu_String AS Make, 
                      UnitData_Vehicle.ManuNS_String AS [Make NS], SUM(CONVERT(money, UnitData_Vehicle_CompCond.Materials_String)) AS [Materials Price], 
                      CONVERT(money, UnitData_Vehicle_CompCond.Labour_String) AS [Labour Price], CONVERT(money, UnitData_Vehicle_CompCond.Combo_String) 
                      AS [Combination Price], CONVERT(money, UnitData_Vehicle_CompCond.PartSpend_String) AS [Parts Price], CONVERT(money, 
                      UnitData_Vehicle_CompCond.SmartRep_String) AS [Smart Price], CONVERT(money, UnitData_Vehicle_CompCond.Estimate_String) 
                      AS [Estimate EX VAT]
FROM         UnitData_Vehicle INNER JOIN
                      UnitData_Vehicle_CompCond ON UnitData_Vehicle.InspectionResultId = UnitData_Vehicle_CompCond.InspectionResultId
WHERE     (UnitData_Vehicle.InspectionProcedureName LIKE '%- inspection') AND (DATEDIFF(day, UnitData_Vehicle.InspectionDateTime, GETDATE()) = 2)
AND Reg_String = 'AB12ABC'
GROUP BY UnitData_Vehicle.EstimDate_DateTime, UnitData_Vehicle.Reg_String, UnitData_Vehicle.VehID_String, UnitData_Vehicle.Manu_String, 
                      UnitData_Vehicle.ManuNS_String, CONVERT(money, UnitData_Vehicle_CompCond.Labour_String), CONVERT(money, 
                      UnitData_Vehicle_CompCond.Combo_String), CONVERT(money, UnitData_Vehicle_CompCond.PartSpend_String), CONVERT(money, 
                      UnitData_Vehicle_CompCond.SmartRep_String), CONVERT(money, UnitData_Vehicle_CompCond.Estimate_String)
```

Comment: You mean add up the values for each row, per column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT     
UnitData_Vehicle.Reg_String AS Registration, 
UnitData_Vehicle.VehID_String AS [Vendor Code], 
UnitData_Vehicle.Manu_String AS Make, 
UnitData_Vehicle.ManuNS_String AS [Make NS], 
SUM(CONVERT(money, UnitData_Vehicle_CompCond.Materials_String)) AS [Materials Price], 
SUM(CONVERT(money, UnitData_Vehicle_CompCond.Labour_String)) AS [Labour Price], 
SUM(CONVERT(money, UnitData_Vehicle_CompCond.Combo_String)) AS [Combination Price], 
SUM(CONVERT(money, UnitData_Vehicle_CompCond.PartSpend_String)) AS [Parts Price], 
SUM(CONVERT(money, UnitData_Vehicle_CompCond.SmartRep_String)) AS [Smart Price], 
SUM(CONVERT(money, UnitData_Vehicle_CompCond.Estimate_String)) AS [Estimate EX VAT]
FROM         UnitData_Vehicle INNER JOIN UnitData_Vehicle_CompCond 
ON UnitData_Vehicle.InspectionResultId = UnitData_Vehicle_CompCond.InspectionResultId
WHERE     (UnitData_Vehicle.InspectionProcedureName LIKE '%- inspection') AND (DATEDIFF(day, UnitData_Vehicle.InspectionDateTime, GETDATE()) = 2) AND Reg_String = 'AB12ABC'

GROUP BY UnitData_Vehicle.EstimDate_DateTime, UnitData_Vehicle.Reg_String, UnitData_Vehicle.VehID_String, UnitData_Vehicle.Manu_String,UnitData_Vehicle.ManuNS_String
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is huge and hard to read, but what you need to essentially do is SUM the columns add add a "GROUP BY Reg_string" to the end of your query, obviously do not include the "RecordNumber" in your output as it can not be grouped.

Answer (score 0):

Your query isn't very easy to read, but this is essentially what you'd have to do if all of your fields were in the same table, just amend it to do what you need regarding table joins etc...

```
SELECT  Reg_String), 
        SUM(Parts) As Parts, 
        SUM(Materials) AS Materials,
        SUM(Labour) AS Labour,
        SUM(Combo) AS Combo,
        SUM(Smart) AS Smart,
        SUM(TotalEstimate) AS TotalEstimate
FROM MyTable
WHERE Reg_String = 'AB12ABC'
GROUP BY Reg_String
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not committing mistake , Total Estimate = Labour + Combo + Smart ?
Below is the query

```
SELECT  Reg_String, 
        SUM(Parts) As Parts, 
        SUM(Materials) AS Materials,
        SUM(Labour) AS Labour,
        SUM(Combo) AS Combo,
        SUM(Smart) AS Smart,
        SUM(Labour + Combo + Smart) AS TotalEstimate
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Reg_String
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  MAX(Reg_String), 
        SUM(Parts) As Parts, 
        SUM(Materials) AS Materials,
        SUM(Labour) AS Labour,
        SUM(Combo) AS Combo,
        SUM(Smart) AS Smart,
        SUM(Labour + Combo + Smart) AS TotalEstimate
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Reg_String
```

use  `MAX(Reg_String)` to display Reg_String also since max will return same result because query is grouping by Reg_String

Comment: I think, we should not use the aggregate function here for varchar, group by is doing the job for this column.